# Vuejs: Use v-for to display an array of images from assets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have 100 images named 1.png to 100.png in my assets folder. I want to display them using v-for, but I don't wanna hard code every url for them.

```
<div v-for="n in 100">
    <img src="../assets/photos/(1.png, 2.png...).png">
</div>
```

What should I do for the (1.png, 2.png...)? Should I use put them into data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the `src` dynamically and then use [`v-bind:src`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) to bind the `src` attribute:

```
<div v-for="n in 100">
    <img v-bind:src="`../assets/photos/${n}.png`">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this in a single file component, it just displayed the template string =`../assets/photos/${n}.svg`>. What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the double quotes. Check the update.